# Authorization token not being sent to backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, authorization

I am trying to create a store, and I'm currently working on the front end wishlist, using redux.  I am trying to configure the add to wishlist, but for some reason, I keep getting the error that I did not give it a token.  Everything else works the way it should.

Here is my add to wishlist service:

```
const addWishItem = async (id, token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };

  const response = await axios.post(`${wishData}/add-wish/${id}`, config);

  return response.data;
};
```

and this is my add to wishlist slice:

```
export const addToWishlist = createAsyncThunk(
  "wish/addWishItem",
  async (id, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return wishService.addWishItem(id, token);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message;
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: How do you know there's no token being sent to the server?  Have you inspected the network call?

Comment: In my authorization file in the backend, I set a check to see if there was no token, to throw an error, and that's the error that gets thrown.  I changed the status code from 401 to 403 just to make sure that was the error being thrown, and sure enough, that's the one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass an empty object as the second parameter (request body)

```
  const response = await axios.post(`${wishData}/add-wish/${id}`, {}, config);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that! It worked... Do you mind explaining why that worked? I'm still new to coding, and for a previous project, I didn't need the empty object...

Comment: Sure, here is the post method call signature:
`axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`
In javaScript, as you know, the order of the arguments matters. That means without the `{}`, you're passing `config` as the second parameter and consequently nothing as `config` (which contains the token).
https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro

Comment: Thank you for that.  Can't believe I didn't think to look at the docs lol